# The provided `as` value is incompatible with the `href` value error in next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have three pages

1. home/start which navigates to
2. home/users/[type] which navigates to
3. home/settings/[type].

home/start

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
const Start = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  return (
    <>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          router.push('/home/users/native');
        }}
      >
        GO
      </button>
    </>
  );
};

export default Start;
```

home/users/[type]

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

const User = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  return (
    <>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          router.push('/home/settings/subscription');
        }}
      >
        Go Again
      </button>
    </>
  );
};

export default User;
```

home/settings/type

```
const Settings = () => {
  return <div>Confirm docs</div>;
};

export default Settings;
```

I navigate from `home/start` to `/home/users/native` by clicking on the button, then to `/home/settings/subscription`.Then, I click on the back button to go back to `home/users/native`.Now, when I click on forward button to get to `home/settings/subscription`, I get the following error

**Error: The provided `as` value (/home/settings/subscription) is incompatible with the `href` value (/[type]).**

I am not using `as` anywhere.Can someone point out as to what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

You could use Link instead of a button with onClick.

```
import Link from 'next/link';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
const Start = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  return (
    <>
      <Link to="/home/users/native">
        GO
      </Link>
    </>
  );
};

export default Start;
```

Comment: What if I need to do things before I route to the second page, like send an api request

Comment: @CleverSkull Also, [`next/link`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link) does not have a `to` prop, you probably meant `href` instead.

Comment: Sorry I confused with react router